# Nashorn + Reactjs for Serverside rendering for production advice

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, nashorn

We are looking into using Nashorn (java's javascript engine 1.8+). We have found some concerns:

1. Warm up time is long ( java recommend hit the code *4000* times)
2. Lack of community around it

What do you guys think about using it for production?

Do you guys have any alternative to serverside render with a java backend ?

Answer (score 2):

A few months ago, I did some research of rendering React components server-side on a Java (EE) application server (at least Tomcat), together with MVC 1.0 RI Ozark.

Have a look here at my GitHub repository: https://github.com/dasniko/ozark-react

Especially for warm-up concerns, I'm using a pool of Nashorn engines, where I pre-load all the libraries I need for executing code at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I built [spring-react-boilerplate](https://github.com/pugnascotia/spring-react-boilerplate). Spring uses an instance of the Nashorn engine per-thread, and I've found that once each engine is initialised (on-demand, it seems) then it's pretty quick. The project actually runs the React renderer during compilation, and from a cold start its not all that slow.

Comment: Would this only be used for static pages? If you have dynamic content that is generated at runtime e.g. like a data response

Comment: In the boilerplate project, the Spring server handles the initial request and renders the page server-side using React. It then serialises the Redux store so that the client can pick up where the server left off. Spring ought to be able to handle all the routes that the client can, and ought to be able to populate the Redux store appropriately for any route.